# Is there a way to force a FTP client to issue an ALLO command before transfer?

Tags: networking, ftp, rfc

I'm developing a FTP server, and I would need the file size before the STOR happens, I have seen that there is a command called ALLO, and I was wondering if there is a way to force the client to issue that command, because the client, of course, knows the file size before hand.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Rob Adams is going the right direction, but I disagree with sending `552`, which says you are aborting the transfer; I think that holding the request until they send `ALLO` is a more useful approach.  Reading through [RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt):

```
        This (ALLO) command may be required by some servers to reserve
        sufficient storage to accommodate the new file to be
        transferred...
```

*Section 4.2* lists the valid format of replies, where you can display the error on the first line, and elaborate on the requirement for `ALLO` on the 2nd line.

Furthermore, *Section 4.2.2* lists this message...  `350 Requested file action pending further information.`

It seems reasonable that if your server receives a request to store before recieving an `ALLO`, it should throw a `350` and hold the transfer until either you get a session timeout, close or they send an `ALLO`.

Comment: I will try that when I arrive home. I hope FileZilla agree with the 350 :D

Comment: @vtortola, if I'm reading [this bug](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/6507) correctly, it looks like they have not implemented `ALLO` yet

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess -- you could return `552 - Exceeded storage allocation (for current directory or
             dataset).`
 for the STOR.

Comment: hmm... no luck :) Response:
Command: STOR eLqEL.jpg
Response: 512 Exceeded storage allocation (for current directory or dataset). Thanks.
Error: Critical file transfer error